# How can a spectrogram of a sound be plotted between a defined upper and lower frequency bound?

Tags: sound, frequency, sox, plot

I would like to plot a spectrogram of a sound between a range of frequencies, specifically from 0 kHz to 2000 Hz. Using SoX (`sox sound.wav -n spectrogram -x 1000 -y 800`), I have been able to make a plot, but I have not been able to set the vertical frequency axis to the range I require:

[image]

How might this be done? I am happy to use a different program.

Comment: What have you tried? Your sample just sets the graph size.  I'd expect things like rate, and -X -Y might be applicable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have looked at [SoX documentation](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) and `-y` changes the height of the image produced while `-Y` changes the height of the plot as it appears in the image. Neither changes the limits or range of the vertical axis for frequency. I've confirmed this in usage tests.

Comment: Stick in -r 4k in front of sound.wav -- works for me to reduce the vertical frequency to 2k (one half the sampling rate).